# how to get the width of textView in android

Tags: android, textview

This is the code what i am using...

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="AMIT KUMAR" />
```

and here is a java code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Log.d("left", textView.getLeft() + " " + textView.getRight() + " "
            + textView.getWidth()+" "+textView.getHeight());
}
```

for all above i am getting the output 0.

so how can i get the width and height of textView.

Comment: what's parent view of this textview?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591784/android-get-width-returns-0

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Try like this:

```
textView.setText("GetHeight");
textView.measure(0, 0);       //must call measure!
textView.getMeasuredHeight(); //get height
textView.getMeasuredWidth();  //get width
```

Answer (score 5):

On your **onCreate** do this then you will get actual **width** and **height** of the **textView**

```
textView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                textView.invalidate();
                float dw = textView.getWidth();
                float dh = textView.getHeight();                
                Log.v("",dw + " - " + dh);              
            }
        }, 1);
```

If you need to get width, height before view drawn then you can do this

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            float dw = textView.getWidth();
            float dh = textView.getHeight();

            System.out.print(dw +" - "+dh);


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: ya i got the answer, but will you pls explain why you are using this code. means runnable thread

Comment: The runnable doesn't get run until the layout has occurred. So it will wait until the view is displayed in screen and for this reason it will always gives correct width, height. But it will fail if you need to calculate width height before view drawn.